# Как из вложенного класса обратится к объекту внешнего класса?

Tags: java, классы

Как из вложенного класса правильно обратится к объекту внешнего класса?

```
public class FirstClass{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // объект к которому надо обратится

    public static SecondClass{
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если внутренний класс нестатический, то вот так: `FirstClass.this.frame`

В вашем случае нужно сделать `frame` статическим полем, т.к. доступ из статического кода к нестатическому невозможен. Тогда переменную из вложенного класа можно будет получить вот так: `FirstClass.frame`